# Jquery - text cannot be changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, text

Good day,
I got this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tswc19go/2/
Basically my javascript file will change content of div every day a week, but calling

```
$("#qoute-name").text(quotes.quote[2].name)
```

does not change text of my element even if i call it in inspector. How is that? I got my Jquery lib loaded before this js file and alerting my value will return it correctly.
Thank you all for possible hints

Comment: Typo - quote / qoute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#quote-image").css("background", 'url(' + quotes.quote[day].imageUrl + ')')
$("#quote-text").text(quotes.quote[2].text)
$("#quote-name").text(quotes.quote[2].name)
```

change lines 13-15 with above lines